# Why can't I return only in a nested body of my Method and not be forced to return in the scope of the main method?

Tags: c#

Why is it that if you declare a return type on a method, that you have to specify a return in the scope of that method? Meaning, if I have a If/Switch in my method I can't specify the return there "ALONE" and not in the main method body? Is the only way around this is to assign the value returned by the nested procedure to a variable and return the variable in the main body of the method?

Example:

```
public Int GetNum()
{
   var a = 1;
   switch(a)
   {
      case 1:
        return 1 + 5;
      default:
        return a;
   }
 return a;   //Why must I specify this return if it is going to hit my switch statement
             //and return some int.
}
```

Comment: Check your example. I think you will find that the return a; outside the switch is not necessary after you correct "int" to make it compileable.

Comment: Its not necessary if all paths return a value, with a default statement that would the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a `default`, that's not necessary.

If you don't have a `default`, you need an outer `return` in case none of the `case`s execute.